# How to lock records in Redshift when they are in work

Tags: php, amazon-redshift

I am going to do a cycle process like:

1. CRON runs script `process.php` which takes 1000 urls;
2. `process.php` works with those urls (up to 20 min);
3. CRON runs `process.php` again and I want it to take next (different) 1000 urls;

How can I prevent getting urls which are already in process?

P.S.

`process.php` runs every 10 min

Table format see above.

```
+----+------+
| id |  url |
+----+------+
| 1  | url1 |
| 2  | url2 |
| 3  | url3 |
| 4  | url4 |
| 5  | url5 |
+----+------+
```

Comment: Is your Id column a monotonically increasing number? Can your php program save the largest id  that it has retrieved? You could update the table with a column indicating that it has been processed. Or you can even have a job status table that gets updated with the ids that have already been retrieved.

Comment: Yes, my ID column is increasing. Updates are very slow in Redshift, that's why we can not mark urls with "in progress" flag. The last option is a bit trivial and I want to leave it for later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches to this "process once" requirement. The choice often depends upon:

- How quickly records are 'grabbed'
- Whether records are processed in parallel
- How to handle processing failures

Here's some ideas:

**Use a queue**

You could create a queue using **Amazon Simple Queuing Service (SQS)**. First, run a job that extracts the URLs from the database and puts them in a queue message. Then, `process.php` can read the details from the queue instead of the database.

While the script is running, the SQS message is *invisible* so other processes can't get it. When the process is finished, it should delete the message from the queue. If the process fails mid-way, the invisible message reappears after a pre-defined interval to be reprocessed.

Queues are a standard way of processing many records. It allows the processing to be distributed over multiple applications/servers. You could even insert single URLs into the queue rather than batching.

**Mark them as processed in the database**

Add a `processed_timestamp` column to the database. When a URL is processed, do an `UPDATE` command on the database to mark the URL as processed. When retrieving URLs, only `SELECT` ones that have *not* been processed.

**Remember last processed**

When retrieving URLs, store the 'last processed' ID number. This could be stored in another database table, in a cache, a disk file, an S3 file, or anywhere that is generally accessible. Then, retrieve this value to determine which records next need to be processed and update it when starting a batch of URLs.

Comment: Thank you John! Nice approaches. I have already been implementing the 3th one with storing last ID in Redis.